# Implementation of Facebook ads for an react-native app (iOS, android)

Tags: typescript, react-native, facebook, addition

I wanted to promote app on Facebook by adding Facebook ads (like.. Myntra and flip-card  did) in react-native for iOS and android.

Comment: So, what's the question? :D

Comment: @BL4DERUNNER steps to implement it in react native

Comment: Do you mean advertisement? If so, then change adds to ads.

Comment: Actually I wanted to know how to implement it in react native, or it is possible or not in react native?